# How to write a partioner in such case for hadoop?

Tags: java, python, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a key like "signature[white space]date[white space]time", but I want all key which has the same signature in the same bin. How to write a partioner for such situation?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

By default HashParititioner used, and whole hashcode used to calculate reducer number. To achieve your task, you can hash only part of you key (signature in your case) and all keys with same signature would be assigned to the same reducer.

Try this code:

```
public class HashPartitioner<K, V> extends Partitioner<K, V> {

   public int getPartition(K key, V value,int numReduceTasks) {

      return key.toString().split("\s+")[0].hashCode() % numReduceTasks;
   }
}
```

Comment: some commentary might help understanding

Comment: I write a custom partitioner like above, but I meet another issue, could you help look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191468/how-to-specify-the-partitioner-for-hadoop-streaming